# Filtering reverse Django relationships using same kwargs for different instances of same model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm relatively new to Django and I was trying to build a chat server from ground up using Django 2.0.5.

I just made the following models today.

```
class DateTimeModel(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Room(DateTimeModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class RoomMember(DateTimeModel):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='members')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'member "{}" in room "{}"'.format(self.user, self.room)

class Message(DateTimeModel):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(RoomMember, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '"{}" sent by "{}"'.format(self.text, self.sender)
```

Now I want to be able to run a query for a room given that I have a list of users. I tried the [Q() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) from Django docs in the following way

```
Room.objects.filter(Q(members__user=foo) & Q(members__user=bar))
```

but this yielded and empty QuerySet for me. Interestingly, if I search for

```
Room.objects.filter(Q(members__user=foo))
```

only, then I get a QuerySet of all Rooms that contain the certain user foo. But this filtering is not specific enough for my needs. So I assume that this is not the right way to do it. Could anyone please point me to the right resource or suggest another approach if there is one? I'm using SQLite if that helps in any way.

Thanks in advance,

Ahmed

Comment: Well here you specify that the *same* related user should be `foo` and `bar` at the same time. So unless `foo == bar`, this will *always* yield an empty queryset.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah I thought so. Any way to modify my queries would be helpful.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to find? Are you searching for a room that contains both foo and bar as members?

Comment: @DanielRoseman correct. Essentially, I should be able to find a room for a given list of users. For example, if I want to locate a group chat room between David, Goliath, and God, I want to be able to make a query and find out that exact room to get all the messages in it.

Comment: It is a bit underspecified what you want: do you want (a) all rooms where foo or (!) bar occur, (b) rooms where foo and (!) bar occur, what if the room is booked by more users?

Comment: @AhmedIshtiaque: say you look for Alice and Bob, and the room is booked by Alice, Bob and Cindy, do you want to return that room?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for now, if I can get a room which contains two distinct users in it, that would be awesome. I haven't given the group chat concept a lot of thought yet. Figured I'd make it for a two-person chat while keeping the flexibility in mind for the future.
Edit: in the Alice and Bob situation, if Cindy joins those two, another room should be created that's distinct from the chatroom between Alice and Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not required, but your queries become easier if you define a ManyToManyField from Room to User. This can use your existing RoomMember model as a through table, so doesn't need any database changes, but you should drop the members related_name so that you can use that name for the m2m:

```
class Room(DateTimeModel):
    ...
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='RoomMember')
```

Now you can do:

```
Room.objects.filter(member=foo).filter(member=bar)
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I want for now. Thank you so much! If there's a suggestion as to how I could make the title more relevant that would be appreciated. I feel like I ended up posting here because I didn't know what to search for exactly.